# Zend framework 2 child_route

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a child_route for my index page but unfortunately it's not routed to that action.
The route script for that is:

```
'home' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            "may_terminate" => true,
            "child_routes" => array(
                "support" => array(
                    "type" => "segment",
                    "options" => array(
                        "route" => "/support",
                        "defaults" => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                            'action' => 'support',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I've also used the same structure into another module on the same ZF2 project where it worked. Can you help me with a hint about my mistake?

The similar route configuration which works on the other module is this one:

```
"post" => array(
            "type" => "literal",
            "options" => array(
                "route" => "/blog",
                "defaults" => array(
                    "controller" => "Blog\Controller\List",
                    "action" => "index",
                ),
            ),
            "may_terminate" => true,
            "child_routes" => array(
                "detail" => array(
                    "type" => "segment",
                    "options" => array(
                        "route" => "/:id[/]",
                        "defaults" => array(
                            "action" => "detail",
                        ),
                        "constraints" => array(
                            "id" => "[1-9]\d*"
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                "admin" => array(
                    "type" => "segment",
                    "options" => array(
                        "route" => "/admin[/]",
                        "defaults" => array(
                            "action" => "admin",
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add child routes to the home route. I know it seems like a logical approach, but it usually ends in confusion and unnecessary verbosity.

The route you've setup is for `//support`, which presumably wasn't your intention. Although removing the initial slash should fix it, I'd suggest just moving your support route out from under home, and then it should work fine as is.

(Note: child routes are fine in general, I just prefer to keep the home route separate.)